# Extend/Create generic method to filter data

Tags: c#, .net, linq

currently I'm executing an EF query to retrieve data from the database, after that I'm trying to filter that data with some custom filters, this is what I've so far:

```
public async Task<object> GetData(CustomFilters customFilters)
{
    IQueryable<CustomDTO> customDTO;
    var query = some EF query...

    var response = await query.ToListAsync();
    //Queryable object with all my rows from database.
    customDTO = response.AsQueryable();

    //Here I want to execute some filters
    FilterByActive(ref customDTO, customFilters.IsActive);
    FilterByStatus(ref customDTO, customFilters.Status);
}

private void FilterByActive(ref IQueryable<CustomDTO> customDTO, bool? isActive)
{
    if (!isActive.HasValue)
        return;

    customDTO = customDTO.Where(a => a.IsActive == isActive).ToList().AsQueryable();
}

private void FilterByStatus(ref IQueryable<CustomDTO> customDTO, int? status)
{
    if (!status.HasValue || status < 0)
        return;

    customDTO = customDTO.Where(a => a.Status == status).ToList().AsQueryable();
}
```

The code is working as expected. My question is if **there is a way to create a generic filter method instead of creating one method for each filter that I want to add** something like this:

```
private void Filtering(ref IQueryable<CustomDTO> customDTO, customFilters)
{
    foreach (var filter in customFilters)
    {
        customDTO = customDTO.Where(x => filter.ColumnName == filter.MyCustomFilter);
    }
}
```

Comment: LINQ methods are already generic and accept `Expression<Func<T,...>>` objects. Are you looking for *dynamic* methods perhaps? A way to generate queries based on a list of fields or conditions?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes! I want to generate some queries based on filters inside my customFilters object.

Comment: The methods you posted are wrong to begin with. Putting `ToList()` after every query will just load everything in memory. If EF complains that a query can't be translated to SQL, fix the query instead just using `ToList()` to silence the error. Loading 100K rows in memory by accident is *slow*

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your comment! I already changed my filter methods and now I'm just using .AsQueryable()

Comment: You can use reflection to build an `Expression<Func<CustomDto,bool>>` which you pass in to the `Where` method

Comment: Unless you really know what you are doing, you should not be using `AsQueryable`. If the original is already `IEnumerable` (e.g. a `List`) then it does nothing useful. If it is already an  `IQueryable` then it does nothing.

Comment: You could build a `Dictionary` to map `ColumnName`s to `Expression<Func<>>` and then use the entry in the `Where`. This isn't trivial. Your best bet may be to investigate [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) or [Dynamic LINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)..